# Xamarin Button Command Binding

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, command

I've got a pretty basic test page called `SettingsPage` which contains a button in the xaml as follows:

```
<Button Text="Toggle Compass" Command="{Binding toggleCompassCmd}"/>
```

A class `CompassTest` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and adds a new command called `toggleCompassCmd`:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Input;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace HelloWorld.Models
{
public class CompassTest : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Set speed delay for monitoring changes.
    SensorSpeed speed = SensorSpeed.UI;

    public ICommand toggleCompassCmd { private set; get; }

    private CompassData m_data;
    protected CompassData compassData
    {
        get { return m_data; }
        private set { m_data = value; }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public CompassTest()
    {
        // Register for reading changes, be sure to unsubscribe when finished
        Compass.ReadingChanged += onCompassReadingChanged;

        // setup toggle command
        toggleCompassCmd = new Command(
            execute: () =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is execute of toggleCompassCmd!");
                toggleCompass();
            },
            canExecute: () =>
            {
                return true;     
            });

    }

    void onCompassReadingChanged(object sender, CompassChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var data = e.Reading;
        Console.WriteLine($"Reading: {data.HeadingMagneticNorth} degrees");
        // Process Heading Magnetic North

        compassData = data;
        onPropertyChanged("compassData");
    }

    protected void onPropertyChanged(string propName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("DateTime"));
        }
    }

    public void toggleCompass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("toggleCompass()");
        try
        {
            if (Compass.IsMonitoring)
                Compass.Stop();
            else
                Compass.Start(speed);
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("FeatureNotSupportedException: " + fnsEx.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
}
```

In the xaml class, I have a member of type `CompassTest`, which should receive the command, like so:

```
public SettingsPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        compass = new CompassTest();
    }
```

However, everything compiles, but nothing fires. How do I "redirect" a command to a member?

Comment: You havent set the binding context. You have to link your settings page with CompassTest. Also i would recommend using some MVVM framrwork so CrossMVVM or FreshMVVM or any other. (Personal recommendation is Fresh).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your pages' `BindingContext` to the object holding the command. In your case:

```
public SettingsPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    compass = new CompassTest();
    BindingContext = compass;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand! But that raises one new question: What if I want a new command to be directed to a different class than `CompassTest`? Can a page have multiple `BindingContext`s?

Comment: No, normally you would have one page and one pagemodel (or view and viewmodel) and that pagemodel would hold all commands, and logic, etc. Your page can only have one `BindingContext`. So, that is something you need to take into account architecture wise. You can have multiple in the same page by moving the command to your page or use events on your button like Tapped, but that would make reusability and maintainability of your code go down.

Comment: Thank you very much! That's indeed good to know! You could easily have the one page model redirect/dispatch all the events to members.

Comment: You probably want to look at a pattern like mvvm which is a good fit with Xamarin.Forms. Please accept as an answer also if this helped you!